# How can I find better quality video streams to my Android phone?

Tags: applications, video, 3g, streaming, netflix

I'm looking for an app that will stream television and/or movies to my phone on 3G. I have a long commute and find that apps I've used (tv.com mainly) have poor selection or quality. Since Android does not have Netflix or Hulu available, what are some other apps that would allow me to watch streaming video without considerable lag?

Comment: "List of X" sites are generally discouraged here. Please read the FAQ.

Comment: Sorry about that. I wasn't asking for "favorite" - merely what other apps were out there.

Comment: It's generally better to ask how to solve a particular problem. In this case, "How can I get better quality out of the television/movies I stream to my device" might get you what you need.

Answer (score 1):

Today Netflix released an [offical App](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.netflix.mediaclient&feature=search_result)!

> Currently Netflix playback is
> supported on the following phones:
>
> HTC Incredible with Android 2.2
>
> HTC Nexus One with Android 2.2, 2.3
>
> HTC Evo 4G with Android 2.2
>
> HTC G2 with Android 2.2
>
> Samsung Nexus S with Android 2.3

Comment: Unfortunately, I have a Samsung Captivate (AT&T Galaxy S) and my phone is not supported. My new question is if I root my phone, would I be able to sideload the app and test if it works? Should I ask a new question for that?